# Create instance of generic class with proper concrete type

Tags: c#, generics, service-locator

I want to implement a generic entity validation mechanism on top of EF validation framework. What I did is created a generic interface with a single `Validate()` method, which will be implemented by different entity validators. Then I use the service locator pattern to instantiate the relevant concrete validator implementation inside the EF `ValidateEntity` method override. Here's my implementation:

**Validator interface**

```
public interface IEntityValidator<T>
{
    DbEntityValidationResult ValidateEntity(T entity);
}
```

**Validator implementation**

```
public class BranchValidator<Branch>: IEntityValidator<Branch>
{
    ClientContext clientContext;

    public BranchValidator(ClientContext clientContext)
    {
        this.clientContext = clientContext;
    }

    public DbEntityValidationResult ValidateEntity(Branch entity)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Service locator (validation locator)**

```
public static class ValidatorLocator<T>
{
    public static IEntityValidator<T> validatorObject;

    public static IEntityValidator<T> GetValidator(string entityType, ClientContext clientContext)
    {
        switch (entityType)
        {
            case "User":
                validatorObject = new UserValidator<T>(clientContext);
                break;
            case "Branch":
                validatorObject = new BranchValidator<T>(clientContext);
                break;
            default:
                validatorObject = null;
                break;
        }

        return validatorObject;
    }

    public static void Validate(T obj)
    {
        validatorObject.ValidateEntity(obj);
    }
}
```

**inside ValidateEntity method in the ClientContext**

```
public partial class ClientContext : DbContext
{
    public ClientContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
    }

    protected override DbEntityValidationResult ValidateEntity(DbEntityEntry entityEntry, IDictionary<object, object> items)
    {
        var entityName = entityEntry.Entity.GetType().FullName; 

        IEntityValidator<T> validatorObj = (T)ValidatorLocator.GetValidator(entityName, this);


        return base.ValidateEntity(entityEntry, items);
    }
}
```

I'm getting compiler error in the `ValidateEntity` method - on the following line:

```
IEntityValidator<T> validatorObj = (T)ValidatorLocator.GetValidator(entityName, this);
```

The error says: *Using the generic type 'ValidatorLocator' requires 1 type arguments*

What is the correct way to return a concrete instance of my generic type?

Comment: To fix that error, you need to do `ValidatorLocator<T>.GetValidator(...)`. However your code isn't going to work like this anyway.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you pls point out what is wrong here?

Comment: Well in the `ValidateEntity` method, what is `T`?

Comment: It would be a different entity type, for example, in the above BranchValidator, T would be a Branch object, in UserValidator, it would be a User object - both are EF entities

Comment: Yes, but your code is using `T` and not one of those types, you can't do that.

Comment: Well, in my BranchValidator implementation, I'm passing a Branch object to the method. Also, i modified the code as you mentioned (See the code update). Now I'm getting the error 'T' could not be found.

Comment: That's exactly my point, when you call a generic method, you need to tell the compiler what type you are using, you can't just say `T`.

Comment: Also, I have rolled back your edit because it changes the whole question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a something like a dependency injection container:

```
public class ClientContext { }

public interface IEntityValidator<T> { }

public class Branch { }
public class BranchValidator : IEntityValidator<Branch>
{
    public BranchValidator(ClientContext clientContext)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Creating a BranchValidator with context {0}", clientContext);
    }
}

public class Other { }
public class OtherValidator : IEntityValidator<Other> { }

public static class ValidatorLocator
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Type> ValidatorContainer
        = new Dictionary<Type, Type>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Use this method to register the validator class for an entity type.
    /// It should have a constructor with ClientContext parameter
    /// </summary>
    public static void RegisterValidator<TEntity,TEntityValidator>()
        where TEntityValidator : IEntityValidator<TEntity>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("=== RegisterValidator ===");
        Console.WriteLine("Registering {0} to validate {1}:", 
            typeof(TEntityValidator), typeof(TEntity));
        ValidatorContainer.Add(typeof(TEntity), typeof(TEntityValidator));
        Console.WriteLine("  Checking constructor with ClientContext parameter"); 
        var ctorParamTypes = new[] {typeof(ClientContext)};
        var validatorCtor = typeof(TEntityValidator).GetConstructor(ctorParamTypes);
        if (validatorCtor == null)
            Console.WriteLine("  Couldn't find the constructor!!");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("  Successfully registered!");
    }

    public static IEntityValidator<TEntity> GetValidator<TEntity>(ClientContext clientContext)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("=== GetValidator ===");
        Console.WriteLine("Getting validator for {0}", typeof(TEntity));
        var validatorType = ValidatorContainer[typeof(TEntity)];
        Console.WriteLine("  Looking for the constructor");
        var ctorParamTypes = new[] {typeof(ClientContext)};
        var validatorCtor = validatorType.GetConstructor(ctorParamTypes);
        Console.WriteLine("  Constructor found");
        var ctorParams = new[] {clientContext};
        Console.WriteLine("  Creating validator");
        var validator = validatorCtor.Invoke(ctorParams);
        Console.WriteLine("  Succesfully created");
        return (IEntityValidator<TEntity>)validator;
    }
}
```

To use it, you must register the validator class for each entity type, and then you can find the service constructor and invoke it. There are variations for this technique: for example you can register a singleton instance of each validator and reuse it, instead of looking for the constructor and invoking it in every use.

NOTE: *obvously the `Console.WriteLine`'s are there to see what's going on, but are not necessary on a real implementation*

Usage example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ValidatorLocator.RegisterValidator<Branch,BranchValidator>();
        ValidatorLocator.RegisterValidator<Other,OtherValidator>();

        var clientContex = new ClientContext();
        ValidatorLocator.GetValidator<Branch>(clientContext);

        Console.WriteLine("Press a key to exit!!");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```